# Adding files for one click installation. Error when adding a manifest file

Tags: manifest, oneclick

I’m working with OpenWebKitSharp and trying to include the files in when I go to publish using one click. I've almost got my project working but I'm having trouble with the OpenWebKitSharp.manifest file. Everything works fine when I debug and I have been able to get it to install use the "Visual Studio Installer." However, I would like to use the One Click installer so it will check for updates automatically. So I've copied all the files into my project and set up the references so that WebKitSharp installs when everything else installs. On all the WebKitSharp files, I set "Build Action" to "Copy" and "Copy to Output" to "Copy if newer" (as I said earlier, everything copies fine into the debug folder and runs correctly). I switch over and use "PublishWizard" and publish it to a folder. Everything shows up in the install folders correctly.

However, now I go and install it on the computer. When done it tries to run the program, I get an error saying. "Activation Context has not been initialized." Well after a little debugging, I have figured out that, when I click to install onto a computer, the "OpenWebKitSharp.manifest" contents is completely changed. If I copy the old file and paste it into the installation directory over writing the new file it created, everything works fine.

How do I solve this problem?

P.S.This may or may not be related, but I have some TrueType fonts (TTF) that don't seem to copy into my install folder. They do copy into my debug folder, just not when I go to publish.

Comment: Have you found the answer maybe?